# iterating through argv pointer to char pointers

Tags: c

Below is taken from C Programming Language p. 117

find -nx pattern is the command with -nx and pattern arguments. When this command is invoked, the following main function is invoked. On the 1st iteration of the 2nd while loop, i can see char n is assigned to c, it then hits case n statement, then the 2nd iteration of the 2nd while loop, this 2nd iteration is supposed to assign char x to c, but i cannot see how that can be the case! For me, the 2nd iteration is still retrieving char n for the expression *++argv[0]

[image]

Comment: Do not put image of code!

Comment: @SouravGhosh This is not source code the OP tries to compile, it is from the book that the OP tries to understand.

Comment: @thebusybee and your point is? It's a code that's part of the question anyways, so it better be in text form.

Comment: Just FYI: This code is very old and badly written according to modern standards.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The objective behind the rule "no screenshots of source" is to be able to reproduce the result an OP gets, mostly in case of errors, without having to re-type all the stuff. In this case we can be just nice and accept the image, because it is just a question of understanding source that does not exist in text for the OP.

Comment: @SouravGhosh While you have a point that it's not equally important, I still think there's no reason to make exceptions to that rule. If I were to answer this question, I would probably take *the existing code* and then add a printf statement in a loop to show what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer `argv[0]` was incremented in the 1st iteration of the loop. If the argument is "-nx", it points to 'x'.

The expression `*++argv[0]`

1. Accesses `argv[0]`.
2. Increments the pointer stored there (`++...`).
3. Dereferences the character pointed to *after* the increment (`*...`).

Since this is really very old code, don't be tempted to learn from it.